# Is it better to always use websockets over http in a realtime app?

Tags: javascript, http, web, websocket

I'm creating a chat application which use websockets, and I would like to know if it's a bad practice to use HTTP requests to send messages and only use the websockets to notify clients ?

Are there any advantages to emitting the message via websockets instead of HTTP if the server have to process it anyway before send it back to the others clients ?

Comment: Depends on what your sending, so I would say it's not always bad practice.  HTTP has the advantage if your sending something that the browser could cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many cases where websockets are faster than HTTP, especially for large numbers of concurrent requests. See [here](https://blog.feathersjs.com/http-vs-websockets-a-performance-comparison-da2533f13a77) for a performance comparison.

For a relatively simple use case like a chat application with a low load, using HTTP for outgoing messages should be fine. Though the performance might be slightly worse.

I personally would find it easier (and a little cleaner) to emit messages via websockets, especially if the socket is already open for clients to be receiving messages.